# Simple subtraction in Verilog

Tags: hex, verilog, difference, subtraction, integer-arithmetic

I've been working on a hex calculator for a while, but seem to be stuck on the subtraction portion, particularly when B>A. I'm trying to simply subtract two positive integers and display the result. It works fine for A>B and A=B. So far I'm able use two 7-segment displays to show the integers to be subtracted and I get the proper difference as long as A>=B

When B>A I see a pattern that I'm not able to debug because of my limited knowledge in Verilog case/if-else statements. Forgive me if I'm not explaining the best way but what I'm observing is that once the first number, A, "reaches" 0 (after being subtracted from) it loops back to F. The remainder of B is then subtracted from F rather than 0.

For example: If A=1, B=3

A - B =

1 - 1 = 0

0 - 1 = F

F - 1 = E

Another example could be 4-8=C

Below are the important snippets of code I've put together thus far.

First, my subtraction statement

```
always@*
    begin
        begin
                 Cout1 = 7'b1000000; //0
        end

case(PrintDifference[3:0])
    4'b0000 : Cout0 = 7'b1000000;   //0
    4'b0001 : Cout0 = 7'b1111001;   //1
    ...
    4'b1110 : Cout0 = 7'b0000110;   //E
    4'b1111 : Cout0 = 7'b0001110;   //F
  endcase
end
```

My subtraction is pretty straightforward

```
output [4:0]Difference;
output [4:0] PrintDifference;
assign PrintDifference = A-B;
```

I was thinking I could just do something like

```
if A>=B, Difference = B-A
else, Difference = A-B
```

Thank you everyone in advance!

Comment: Wraparound is the expected Verilog behavior for underflows. What behavior do you expect instead? If you're looking for the absolute value, as your pseudocode at the end would indicate, you can implement it almost as simply as your pseudocode indicates.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking to avoid wraparound. I want it to give the exact value (so going into the negatives). I'm not sure where I would implement my pseudocode however (in my case statement, outside my case statement, near my assignments).

Comment: it has nothing to do with verilog, it is just simple arithmetic and 2-compliment representation of data. you should read about it, or just try to subtract two binary numbers manually on the piece of paper.

Comment: `4-8=c` is because `-4` becomes `C` with 2's complement format.

Comment: subtraction is implemented using addition  a = b - c = b + (-c).   -c is implemented using invert and add one.  the add one is the carry in  and the invert is just a ones complement.  then add then examine the carry out to determine if there was a borrow or not.  work this out with pencil and paper and it becomes pretty easy...if you get 0xC and you want to display -4 then invert and add one to get the 4 and light up a minus sign...or in parallel subtract a-b and b-a and use whichever one comes out positive (based on the borrow or lack of)

Comment: signed overflow, a number that cannot be represented with that number of bits for signed addition (or subtraction since it is just using an adder) (signed is in the eye of the beholder, twos complement makes it such that the adder doesnt know signed from unsigned) just like the carry out determines unsigned overflow.  signed overflow is if the carry in and carry out of the msbit dont match, but with a simple truth table you can see there is a way to determine it strictly from the msbits of the operands and result (fed to the adder).

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour of twos complement addition / subtraction which I would recommend reading up on since it is so essential.

The result obtained can be changed back into an unsigned form by inverting all the bits and adding one. Checking the most significant bit will tell you if the number is negative or not.